# How to print the values assigned in loop in python?

Tags: python

I have assigned the values to newly created variables in a loop and I want to print the values of the newly created variables.

```
for i,j in zip(range(0,2)):
    exec(f'cat{i} = 1')
```

I want to print cat_0 and cat_1 inside the loop

Comment: What is stopping you? Honestly, there is **never a good reason to create dynamic variables like this**. It is always a bad practice

Comment: What does this have to do with pandas?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel. Pandas are fascinating creatures at all times :)

Answer (score 2):

As commented by Juan, there’s never a good reason to do this. Use a regular list:

```
cat = [0] * 2
for i in range(0, 2):
    cat[i] = 1
```

… I’m assuming the actual code does something more interesting; otherwise you’d just do `cat = [1] * 2` without a loop.

Or, if your `i` is a non-numeric (or a numeric but non-contiguous) value, use a `dict`:

```
cat = {}

for i in ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']:
    cat[i] = 1
```

Though, again, you can write this kind of code more concisely and without a loop:

```
cat = {key: 1 for key in ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']}
```