# I do understand what I did, now

Tags: python, for-loop, lambda, variable-assignment, python-3.8

I was trying to make variables inside a loop. i.e. I pass a pattern of variables, and the pattern of their values and the variables are accordingly created and stored in a text file.

But, I tried something off topic and did this:

```
a = lambda a: a
for i in ["a", "b"]:
    b = eval(i)(a)
    print(i)
```

the output was:

```
a
b
```

Can anyone please explain what has happened here?

Edit:
I have analysed its answer.
I will paste it below.
Please verify if it is correct.
Thank you!

Lets first break the problem in parts.

```
def a(n):
    return n
b = eval("a")(a)
print("a")
b = eval("b")(a)
print("b")
```

We can clearly see that the output is due to the two print statements.

```
print("a")
print("b")
```

Thus the rest of the statements play no part in the output.

```
def a(n):
    return n
b = eval("a")(a)
b = eval("b")(a)
```

These statements can simply be put across like this:

```
def a(n):
    return n
b = a(a)
b = b(a)
```

The statement

```
b = a(a)
```

makes the same effect as

```
def b(n):
    return n
```

Thus the entire code can be put across like this:

```
def a(n):
    return n
def b(n):
    return n
print("a")
print("b")
```

Thus there is no ambiguity in this question now.

Comment: Your looping through ["a", "b"] (a and b) and just printing it. Do print B for different results

Comment: “I was trying to make variables inside a loop.” — **Don’t**. Heed the advice from https://stackoverflow.com/a/64322465/1968.

Comment: I second the nomination: making individual variables with such processing is unnecessary and dangerous.  Work through tutorials on more data structures: lists, dicts, classes, etc. so you have the tools to fit your problems.

Comment: @Prune Thank you!
Btw. I just stumbled across this while working on a project and figured out what had happened the next day.

Btw. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lets first break the problem in parts.

```
def a(n):
    return n
b = eval("a")(a)
print("a")
b = eval("b")(a)
print("b")
```

We can clearly see that the output is due to the two print statements.

```
print("a")
print("b")
```

Thus the rest of the statements play no part in the output.

```
def a(n):
    return n
b = eval("a")(a)
b = eval("b")(a)
```

These statements can simply be put across like this:

```
def a(n):
    return n
b = a(a)
b = b(a)
```

The statement

```
b = a(a)
```

makes the same effect as

```
def b(n):
    return n
```

Thus the entire code can be put across like this:

```
def a(n):
    return n
def b(n):
    return n
print("a")
print("b")
```

Thus there is no ambiguity in this question now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can deconstruct your loop to understand for yourself, and please don't do that as pointed out in the comment.

```py
a = lambda a: a

# First iteration
i = "a"
b = eval(i)(a)
print(i) # a

# Second iteration
i = "b"
b = eval(i)(a) # eval("b") is now <function __main__.<lambda>(a)>
print(i) # b
```

Comment: Exactly, they need to do `print(b)` to get anything meaningful

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the variable i (which takes the values "a" and "b" since you loop over ["a", "b"]). If you want to see which values the variable b takes, print b instead:

```
a = lambda a: a
for i in ["a", "b"]:
   b = eval(i)(a)
   print(b)
```